# Drush: How do I change the Drupal root

Tags: 8, drush

My Drush commands doesn't work because my Drupal files are in another directory than the one set in Drush. Everything is set up to this path so I can't just change the folder name.

```
Drush status
  [..]
  Drupal root   : /Users/nicklas/Documents/SourceTree/Drupal/web
```

How can I change the path to `/docroot` instead of `/web`?

> /Users/nicklas/Documents/SourceTree/Drupal/docroot

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it in via the `--root` argument

`drush status --root=/Users/nicklas/Documents/SourceTree/Drupal/docroot`

Comment: Has this command changed in drush 9 ? My local installation doesn't recognise it

Comment: Mine still works, does it recognize `drush` at all?

Comment: Yes, haven't had any issues with other Drush commands